# How to Adjust the Text Label Color According to the Background Image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using a lot of different background images in my project and I wanted to know how can I adjust the UITextLabel colour according to the Background Image View on my View Controller? i.e. if the background is dark the text will become .white whereas if the background is light the text will become .black. Any help will be highly appreciated:)

Comment: What would you do if some part is light and other is dark in your background ? You can find the color of a pixel at a position. See here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/94041. Then you could average over the textField frame to decide if it is light or dark. Note: unless you know what the background is and can define if it is dark or light ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using third-party libraries, what I would suggest is to use
https://cocoapods.org/pods/ChameleonFramework
to get access to its function

`ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: UIColor, returnFlat: Bool)`

Comment: Could you please let me know how can I assign the colour  depending upon the background to text field using this framework? Thanks!

Comment: If you already know the colour of the background, you can add it immediately to the methold:  

`label.textColor =  ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: YourBackgroundColor, returnFlat: true)`
In case you do not know the precise colour of the background, you can use Digital Color Meter in your Mac and get the colour as a hexadecimal value and use it in the method: 
`let myColour = UIColor(hexString: "HexValueOfTheBackground")` then 
`label.textColor =  ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: myColour, returnFlat: true)`